# How do I use .htaccess to change the structure of my website?

Tags: .htaccess, dns, file-structure

I'm doing some reorganizing on my web server and would like to change the way my structure works.  Currently, everything is stored at the lowest level so that when I access my site the url looks like this:

```
www.example.com
www.example.com/page1.php
```

I have many pages in my site and i would like to move them out of the main folder. eg.

```
www.example.com/folder/
www.example.com/folder/page1.php
```

however, I would like for users not to see the /folder/ section of the url.  In other words, when a user visits my site, I want him to navigate to:

```
www.example.com/page1.php
www.example.com/myfolder1/page1.php
www.example.com/myfolder2/page2.php
www.example.com/anyfoldername/anypagename.php
```

but actually be at

```
www.example.com/folder/page1.php
www.example.com/folder/myfolder1/page1.php
www.example.com/folder/myfolder2/page2.php
www.example.com/folder/anyfoldername/anypagename.php
```

I want the url to show without the /folder at all times.

Is there a way to do this with the .htaccess file?

Comment: You could use mod_rewrite to rewrite /page1.php to /folder/page1.php on the server. But imagine you have page1.php in /folder and page2.php in /folder2. By only accessing www.example.com/page2.php, I think the rewrite engine can't know which folder the file is in, unless you manually set a rewrite for all of the pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily do this using **mod_rewrite**. For example:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^page1\.php$ /folder/page1.php [L]
```

**NOTE:**
This is to be placed in .htaccess in your website root folder. If placed elsewhere some small tweaking may be required.

---

**UPDATE:**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/$1 [L]
```

Comment: This works thanks.  A little clarification. I have almost 100 pages that are nested inside of many folders.  How would I do this same thing, but for all files in all folders?

www.example.com/folder1/folder2/page1.php

Comment: I need to see few examples (from URL => to URL) to spot the pattern. If there is something in common -- I can create a rule (or few rules) that will cover a bunch of pages in 1 go -- it all depends on how it needs to be rewritten: if there is a pattern then it is easy, if not -- then one by one.

Comment: www.example.com/page1.php => www.example.com/folder/page1.php,
www.example.com/page2.php => www.example.com/folder/page2.php,
www.example.com/myfolder1/page1.php => www.example.com/folder/myfolder1/page1.php,
www.example.com/myfolder2/page2.php => www.example.com/folder/myfolder2/page2.php

Comment: I added some clarification to the original question to help with the examples.  the comment section is not meant for many examples, I guess.

Comment: You are AWESOME!  This worked like a charm.  The new organizational structure of my site is much easier to navigate and much cleaner.  I don't know how to thank you enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ folder/$1 [L]
```